# Images.xcassets not included in .app

Tags: ios, xcode

My Images.xcassets is not included in .app bundle.

Images.xcassets does exist.
Target Membership is selected.
In Targets, Build Phases, Copy Bundle Resources  Images.xcassets is included.

What am I missing ?

**UPDATE**
I have added and removed it few times, and now it is working again.

I love Xcode.

Comment: Is the xcassets folder not included or are the images themselves not copied? Usually xcassets folders get "compiled" and the images get copied with a different structure than inside your Xcode project.

Comment: No images. I manage to fix this. I just added it and remove it for few times and now it is working again. I love Xcode

Comment: If you fix something yourself, please delete your questions or post and accept your own answer if you feel that could help other people.

Comment: I added update, for future generations

Answer (score 2):

I have added and removed it few times, and now it is working again.

I love Xcode.

Comment: This is ridiculous. This bug is still present in 6.3.2... i have added/removed, shutdown/restart... done everything. It won't copy the assets over.